# Task queue for wp8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, task, dispatcher

What is a correct way to queue complex tasks in wp8?

The tasks consists of the following:

1. Showing a `ProgressIndicator` through updating a model variable
2. Fetching or storing data to a wcf service (`UploadStringAsync`)
3. Updating potentially data bound model with the result from `UploadStringCompleted`.
4. Hiding the `ProgressIndicator` through updating a model variable

Currently I've been working with a class owning a queue of command objects, running a single thread that is started when an item is added if it's not already running.

I have however problems with waiting for tasks or subtasks where the code stops running.

Previously I've used async await, but a few levels down the behaviour was becoming more and more unpredictable.

What I want is the main thread being able to create and queue command objects.
The command objects should run one at a time, not starting a new one until the previous one is completely finished.
The command objects should be able to use the dispatcher to access the main thread if neccesary.

Comment: `BlockingCollection` ?

Answer (score 6):

If you use `async`/`await`, there's no need for another thread (since you have no CPU-bound processing).

In your case, it sounds like you just need a queue of asynchronous delegates. The natural type of an asynchronous delegate is `Func<Task>` (without a return value) or `Func<Task<T>>` (with a return value). This little tip is unfortunately not well-known at this point.

So, declare a queue of asynchronous delegates:

```
private readonly Queue<Func<Task>> queue = new Queue<Func<Task>>();
```

Then you can have a single "top-level" task that just (asynchronously) processes the queue:

```
private Task queueProcessor;
```

The `queueProcessor` can be `null` whenever there's no more items. Whenever it's not `null`, it'll represent this method:

```
private async Task ProcessQueue()
{
  try
  {
    while (queue.Count != 0)
    {
      Func<Task> command = queue.Dequeue();
      try
      {
        await command();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        // Exceptions from your queued tasks will end up here.
        throw;
      }
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    queueProcessor = null;
  }
}
```

Your `Enqueue` method would then look like this:

```
private void Enqueue(Func<Task> command)
{
  queue.Enqueue(command);
  if (queueProcessor == null)
    queueProcessor = ProcessQueue();
}
```

Right now, I have the exception handling set up like this: any queued command that throws an exception will cause the queue processor to stop processing (with the same exception). This may not be the best behavior for your application.

You can use it like this (with either a lambda or an actual method, of course):

```
Enqueue(async () =>
{
  ShowProgressIndicator = true;
  ModelData = await myProxy.DownloadStringTaskAsync();
  ShowProgressIndicator = false;
});
```

Note the use of `DownloadStringTaskAsync`. If you [write TAP wrappers for your EAP members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#EAP), your `async` code will be more "natural-looking" (i.e., simpler).

This is sufficiently complex that I'd recommend putting it into a separate class, but you'd want to decide how to handle (and surface) errors first.

Comment: I'm wondering what happens if I would call Enqueue twice with enough pause so that the first command is already dequeued and awaiting.

Comment: Good catch! The check in `Enqueue` should be for `queueProcessor`, not `queue.Count`. I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to implement pause / resume with this type of work queue, so that on application close I can pause & persist to DB, or allow the user a chance to wait, and therefore resume the processing.

Am having huge trouble getting it to work though. The cancel is hit & miss, and resuming _queueprocessor = ProcessQueue() doesn't work as it does in Enqueue(). 

Would be good to hear how others would go about this?