# Pausable & resumable async task queue

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-queue, cancellation

I've implemented a work queue based on something I found here > [Task queue for wp8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645171/task-queue-for-wp8) ...but am having trouble implementing additional functionality with it.

I'd taken out the `Func<Task>`'s and replaced them with ICommands (holding their own CancellationTokens), and intended to add `Pause()`, `Resume()`, `Save()` & `Restore()` methods. This is so `OnFormClose()` I can pause the queue processing and prompt the user to decide whether he wants to "wait for the queue to finish" (i.e. resume), or "exit now" (i.e. save and exit).

```
public class WqController
{
    private readonly Queue<ICommand> _queue = new Queue<ICommand>();
    private Task _queueProcessor;
    private ICommand _curCommand;

    public void Enqueue(ICommand command)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(command);

        if (_queueProcessor == null) _queueProcessor = ProcessQueue();
    }

    private async Task ProcessQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            while (_queue.Count != 0)
            {
                _curCommand = _queue.Peek();

                try
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => _curCommand.Execute());
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("QUEUE PAUSED");
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FAILED TO EXECUTE COMMAND");
                }
                _queue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _queueProcessor = null;
            _curCommand = null;
        }
    }

    public async Task Cancel()
    {
        _curCommand.Cts.Cancel(true);
        await _queueProcessor;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        _queueProcessor = ProcessQueue();
    }
}
```

The `Save()` & `Restore()` work fine, so I haven't included them here. The `Cancel()` works intermittently / unreliably, and the `Restore()` doesn't seem to work at all (confusingly to me, as I'm basically attempting just the same restart as works in the `Enqueue()` method).

Comment: It is hard to see how this class holds up any invariants. For example if `Status != WqStatus.Paused` then `Resume` just silently fails. Add asserts making sure that `Resume` is only called when the state is `Paused`. Also, you assume that `_queueProcessor == null`. Add an assert for that as well. And so on.

Comment: I don't *think* that Status or Count are involved in the problem I'm seeing. The resume code is definitely running. Think I'll adjust the code in that respect.

Comment: When I break on `Resume()`, `_queueProcessor`'s status says "WaitingForActivation", if that is any help?

Comment: It seems to me we are missing code to determine what goes on. For example, you talk about cancellation, but where do really check your `CancellationToken` inside the code? i don't see that part.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I'm doing a `_curCommand.Cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` immediately before any long running task in any code called by the commands going through this queue. Your comment has just helped me maybe explain the intermittentness of `Cancel()`. If cancel is called after the last cancellation check has passed, then the exception isn't thrown, and the next command gets loaded (along with a new cancellation token). I've therefore added `if (_curCommand.Cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;` immediately after `_queue.Dequeue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working and thought I should outline my solution here.

It turns out my use of cancellation tokens was a little haphazard, which was preventing this class from functioning as intended. For example, the following issues were relevant:

1. If Cancel was called after the last cancellation check had passed in the command, a new command would be loaded (along with its own new cancellation token), and as such the cancel call would have been lost / ignored. This was solved with `if (_curCommand.Cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;` right after `_queue.Dequeue();`.
2. After a cancel had been called, if the command were to be resumed later, then it would need a new cancellation token (otherwise the existing one with cancel = true would still be active). The line `_curCommand.InvalidateCancellationToken();` does this by setting the token to null, and then my command refreshes the token when next called.

The full code I used:

```
public class WqController
{
    private readonly Queue<ICommand> _queue = new Queue<ICommand>();
    private Task _queueProcessor;
    private ICommand _curCommand;

    public void Enqueue(ICommand command)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(command);

        if (_queueProcessor == null) _queueProcessor = ProcessQueue();
    }

    private async Task ProcessQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            while (_queue.Count != 0)
            {
                _curCommand = _queue.Peek();

                try
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => _curCommand.Execute());
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    _curCommand.InvalidateCancellationToken();
                    Console.WriteLine("QUEUE PAUSED");
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FAILED TO EXECUTE COMMAND");
                }
                _queue.Dequeue();
                if (_curCommand.Cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _queueProcessor = null;
            _curCommand = null;
        }
    }

    public async Task Cancel()
    {
        _curCommand.Cts.Cancel(true);
        await _queueProcessor;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        _queueProcessor = ProcessQueue();
    }
}
```

This all seems to work very smoothly now, and is a big improvement on the Background worker queue implementation I had been using prior.